# struts2 redirecting to default action when working with tiles

Tags: java, struts2, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

i have index.jsp like this

```
<% response.sendRedirect("home.action"); %>
```

i want to invoke that action like `http://localhost:8080/Myapp`

but i want to remove index.jsp and i tried with

```
<default-action-ref name="home"/>
<action name ="home"----
```

but i got 404 error specifying that the action doesnot exist
What to do in this case ?
when i am putting a breakpoint in the action (class) control is not coming to action so i think that `<default-action-ref name="home"/>` is not working

Please provide some helpful inputs?

Comment: If no action is found then it will execute default action. (action handle any unmatched requests, you can specify a default action)

Comment: it must be invoked with http://localhost:8080/Myapp but without that index.jsp

Comment: So, you want to remove `index.jsp` file from your application? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: So becuase of that one my google search engine gives worst rank

Comment: that means it not recognizes redirected keywords,tittle,metatags

Answer (score 0):

I don't thinks it's a good idea but it will fulfill your requirement.

```
<action name="">
    <result type="redirectAction">home</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is a Simple Logic Which I've Used**

```
<action name="regi">
<result name="success" type="tiles">regi.tiles</result>
</action>
<action name="registration" class="com.regform">
<result name="success" type="redirect">regi.action</result>
</action>
```